# git checkout lfs files immediate makes all lfs files modified

Tags: git

Essentially, I just git clone and checkout

```
git lfs clone https://github.com/**/**.git
git checkout -b add_test_for_multi_portfolio  origin/add_test_for_multi_portfolio
```

Then, all my lfs files are considered modified when doing

```
git status
```

This is incredible annoying... Any suggestion?

Comment: `git lfs clone https://github.com/**/**.git` is not a valid git command.. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: just clone the new repo right?

Comment: you do not need `lfs`.. It is just `git lfs clone https://github.com/**/**.git`

Comment: ehm... i don't think the error comes from there... i could still successfully git clone the repo... the key error is that once I git checkout a new branch, all the lfs files are considered modified....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the key error is that once I git checkout a new branch, all the lfs files are considered modified

Check first if you have the settings `core.autocrlf` set to `true`.

If yes, type:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then try and clone again.

---

Regarding LFS itself, see [issue 2435](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2435):

If you see something like:

```
test-lfs - master $> git lfs pull
Git LFS: (19 of 20 files) 196.82 MB / 197.08 MB
Expected OID 7633170d50ca7cfc690f1fca4dde1adc73ef0130b75fc1cb7d4517b1cfdcc5b7, got d10e697da5588ec5c1d580a8c5ee57d105fdfdaadfd9674fef73ba628cf9655c after 9977 bytes written
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://****@bitbucket.org/****/test-lfs.git/info/lfs'test-lfs - master! $> git lfs status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [ ruby-2.3.1p112 ]
On branch master
Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/master:


Git LFS objects to be committed:

        files/default/firmware/bxtgucver87.tar.bz2 (LFS: fc1eb19 -> Git: fc1eb19)
        files/default/firmware/kbldmcver101.tar.bz2 (LFS: 2dfb6b1 -> Git: 2dfb6b1)
        files/default/firmware/kblgucver914.tar.bz2 (LFS: 54a8350 -> Git: 54a8350)
```

This can happen for one of two reasons:

> - LFS's filters aren't installed. LFS relies on Git invoking a program called `git lfs filter-process` in order to convert the large files in your working tree to small files in your history.
>     You can double check that these are installed by running:
>
>   ```
>   $ git lfs install
>   $ git config filter.lfs.process # <- should be "git-lfs filter-process"
>   ```
> - Your `.gitattributes` aren't invoking the Git LFS filters, which means that the files aren't being converted.
>     You can double check this by inspecting the contents of your `.gitattributes`, and running `git lfs track` if the pattern you want to be tracked isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer... Anyway, I resolve this issue by updating both git and git-lfs. And then reconstruct a repo, ensuring that .gitattributes contains all the file types that are needed for git-lfs to track and only after that add the corresponding files to git.